# how to forward dns nameserver from WAN to LAN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, dhcp, lubuntu

I have two linux machines (lubuntu to be specific) , one working as router having one ethernet port connected to internet and second to client.[image]
I have configures dhcp server on router as follows

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.1.5 192.168.1.200;
  option domain-name-servers 103.61.253.90; #-> static dns ip address
  option domain-name "www.tendawifi.com"; #-> static dns domain name
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.1.255;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
  default-lease-time 600;
  max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

I want the dns nameserver also be dynamic as per the internet service provider. Although I can get the nameserver using `hostnamectl status` but how to use it in dhcpd.conf file.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an observation. Normally, you'd setup a (caching) DNS forwarder on the router that forwards all DNS queries from LAN clients to upstream DNS servers. You'd put the router's LAN IP as DNS server for it's DHCP clients.

Comment: @Edward how can we do this ? Like any examples or so ..

Comment: Sure. I like bind as a DNS server, you could follow instructions on https://tecadmin.net/setup-forward-only-dns-server-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/ and put the DNS servers of your provider in the bind config file. Then, put the IP address of your router in the dhcpd config file. Remember to allow DNS queries in the firewall.